# jQuery Class selector only selects first element with the class

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Afternoon. Im struggling with this situation.

I have a very simple tabbed content inside an AnythingSlider slide. The tabs work fine for the first slide but, when I switch slides the tab wont work.

Only the first slide works and if i change slides and click on the tabs I can see on Chrome's developer tools that the first slide's tabs are changing.

This is the tabs script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.top5tabs').css("display","block");
        $('.top5tabs div').hide();
        $('.top5tabs div:first').show();
        $('.top5tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
            $('.top5tabs  ul li a').click(function(){
            $('.top5tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
            $('.top5tabs div').hide('fast');
            $(currentTab).show('fast');
        return false;
        });
    });
```

and this is the html that repeats on each one of the slides.

```
<div class="top5tabs">

            <ul class="tabnav">

                <li><a href="#tab-1">option 1</a></li>

                <li><a href="#tab-2">option 2</a></li>

            </ul>

            <div id="tab-1" class="tabdiv">content</div>
            <div id="tab-2" class="tabdiv">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/b62Gq/ Can you up the page itself?

Comment: It does work for 1 element, but when there are multiple tabs in the same page it wont work

Comment: see here. http://jsfiddle.net/b62Gq/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use the same "id" values for multiple elements on the page. You can't do that and expect stuff to work.

When you need multiple sets of tabs, you could switch to using "class" values to identify the `<div>` element to show instead of an "id".

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/b62Gq/2/) is an update of your fiddle with unique "id" values.

*edit* — and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/b62Gq/3/) is the version that keeps the tab control local to each group of tabbed elements.

Comment: Thanks! That fixes one of the problems. However, the content on the second set of tabs is still hidden. It should be showing at load time

Comment: That's because ":first" does not mean, "the first one in that group"; it means, "the first one matched by the overall selector." I'll work on the fiddle and update the answer in a sec.

Comment: I'm usually thinking like this: use class="<identifier"> for something you want to use in several different places, use id="<identifier>" for something unique.

Comment: Thank you so much Pointy, that fixes the problem completely! Ive been working on this site for several hours now and I started to miss some things.